# How do you solve the integral $\int \left(\frac{1}{\sec^4(x)}+1\right)dx$ with any method?

Tags: integration

I am wondering how many ways there are to solve this integral:

$$\int \left(\frac 1 {\sec^4(x)}+1\right) dx$$

I have a solution with one method, but I would like to know how you would solve the integral with the method you prefer.

If it's possible, could you tell me the country you're from, please? I'm conducting an experiment.

Thanks.

Comment: How about you tell us what your method is? It seems like a weird set up for us to solve your homework problems.

Comment: First you have $\dfrac 1 {\sec x} = \cos x.$ But I wonder if you intended $\dfrac 1 {\sec^4 x + 1},$ since otherwise the $\cdots+1$ part is a triviality. $\vphantom{\dfrac 1 1}$

Comment: Can you please stop asking these kinds of “How many ways there are to solve this integral” type question. There are many different ways to solve this problem. If this is a homework question, just straight-out tell us and include what you’ve done so far. Don’t repeat these kinds of questions in the future.

Comment: For reference, this is the first question you’ve asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761948/how-do-you-solve-the-integral-int-frac2x5x22x5-dx-with-any-method

Comment: You have basically two choices here. 1/ is linearising $\cos(x)^4$ because $\cos(nx)$ is easier to integrate. 2/ is starting with partial term $\cos(x)^3\sin(x)$ and add/remove progressively the missing/superfluous terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hint:$$\frac{1}{\sec(x)^4}+1=1+\cos(x)^4=\frac{1}{8} (4 \cos (2 x)+\cos (4 x)+11)$$

Comment: You mean $1/\sec(x)^4$ yes?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry!Ok i have forgotten the exponent is equal to $4$